# tensorflow nvidia gpu docker image - how to combine with anaconda3

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, anaconda, nvidia-docker

I followed [this article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/jupyter-tensorflow-nvidia-gpu-docker-google-compute-engine-4a146f085f17) to setup my GPU server, install CUDA and pull the nvidia-docker image that runs a gpu-enabled tensorflow instance with a jupyter notebook installed.

however, I noticed I do not have anaconda3 inside that in order to update to python 3.6 and update all the packages.

I wasnt able to attach the nividia-docker image and install anaconda3, since all the commands like wget to download are missing.

How would I do it or is there an alternative way?

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is. Did you try installing anaconda and wget and friends?